# How to change modules classloader in websphere?

Tags: websphere, wsadmin

How to change modules classloader to PARENT_FIRST in WebSphere by wsadmin script?

[image]

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_warclmode.html

Did not really help, getting this error message in the last step:
[image]

And another question:

in the deployment.xml is an element "classloader" with the attribute "mode", and an element "modules" with the attribute "classloaderMode". 
What's the difference?

My aim is to change the attribute "classloaderMode" in the "modules" element in the deployment.xml by wsadmin script.

Comment: Hmm, the KC topic you referenced is pretty straightforward, when you said "did not help", what specifically didn't you understand in that topic and I'll try to explain.

Comment: Oh, and to your second question, the difference between the two attributes is one is a classloader order at the application level and one is the classloader order for an individual module of the application.

Comment: is there anything special I have to give attention for while running a jython multiline command in cmd:

for module in myModules:
     if (module.find('WebModuleDeployment')!= -1):
        AdminConfig.modify(module, [['classloaderMode', 'mode']])

Comment: If you're running a multiline command (which this has to be), you really should create a script file and just run it.  Make certain 'mode' in your snippet above is either 'PARENT_FIRST' or 'PARENT_LAST'

Comment: I'll give it a try, thx